# JBPM task instance is "IN_PROGRESS" when the workflow instance is ended

Tags: transition, alfresco, jbpm

In alfresco 4.1, using JBPM, I have defined the following workflow:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<process-definition xmlns="urn:jbpm.org:jpdl-3.1" name="dswf:testworkflow">
    <swimlane name="initiator" />

    <start-state name="start">
        <task name="dswf:startTask" swimlane="initiator"/>
        <transition name="" to="wait" />
    </start-state>

    <task-node name="wait">
        <task name="dswf:waitCompletion">
            <event type="task-create">
                <action class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.jbpm.AlfrescoJavaScript">
                    <script>
                        logger.log("Waiting");
                    </script>
                </action>
            </event>
        </task>
        <transition name="complete" to="completed" />
    </task-node>

    <node name="completed">
        <event type="node-enter">
            <action class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.jbpm.AlfrescoJavaScript">
                <script>
                    logger.log("Completed");
                </script>
            </action>
        </event>
        <transition name="" to="end" />
    </node>
    
    <end-state name="end" />
</process-definition>
```

Using the following java code, I have fired the transition from wait to completed:

```java
/* Suppose that workflowInstanceId is the id of an instance of this workflow */
List<WorkflowPath> paths = workflowService.getWorkflowPaths(workflowInstanceId);
if (paths != null && paths.size() != 0) {
    for (WorkflowPath wp : paths) {
        try {
            /* checkTransition() returns true if the path contains the transition "complete" */
            boolean hasComplete = checkTransition(wp, "complete");
            if (hasComplete) {
                workflowService.signal(wp.getId(), "complete");
            }
        }
        catch (WorkflowException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Before executing the code I can see in the workflow console that the workflow instance is in the correct task and there is the transition `complete`.

When the code is execute, the command:

show workflows all

does not return any workflows.

Everything seems ok, but there seems to be a problem.
The task instance `wait` is still in `IN_PROGRESS` and so it is returned by a webscript even though the workflow instance does not exist anymore.

Comment: are you using jbpm because you're supposed to do so? use activiti instead if you're allowed to do so

Comment: Hi Alfrescian, are you trying to evade the question? :)
Yes, I have to use jbpm. Thank you for your help!

Comment: no, I'm just no more familiar with jbpm & jbpm integration in alfresco as there's activiti since Alfresco 3.4

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but I've got an answer. I'm not sure if it's the right answer for you.

I had the same issue and Signalling didn't work. So I used the following

```xml
<action class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.jbpm.AlfrescoJavaScript">
  <script>
    <variable name="wf_ended" access="read,write" />
    <expression>wf_ended = true;</expression>
  </script>
</action>

<script>
  executionContext.getTaskMgmtInstance().endAll();
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Tahir. I do not remember how I solved the problem. I forgot to update this question. I do not have the time to verify if your question is right. What do you think is wrong in my code?

Comment: The problem with Signal is, that it goes to the next step. But if that step is end, it doesn't end the task hence you see the status in_progress. So by ending it, it really ends and completes it.